# MVC4 and jQuery/AJAX - Error not found when posting JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Ajax (and jQuery UI) and when i press a button on the dialog i trigger the following action in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeletePost(int adrId)
{
   return Json("Hello World Json!", JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

My JQuery Code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#dialog").dialog(
        {
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/DeletePost',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { adrId: 6 },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        error: function (xhr) {
                            alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            CheckIfInvoiceFound(result);
                        },
                        async: true,
                        processData: false
                    });
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }

            }
        });
    jQuery('.delete').click(function () {

    })
})</script>
```

However, when i POST to the server, i get an "Error: Not Found"

Comment: Try adding `traditional:true` to the ajax parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `data` parameter not being a valid JSON payload.

It is not valid JSON, because jQuery is using the `jQuery.param()` method internally to prepare the request parameters for typical POST submissions, and it will get converted to the following string:

```
adrId=6
```

However, the server is expecting a JSON payload, and what you specified is clearly not a JSON payload. A valid JSON payload would be:

```
{ 'adrId': 6 }
```

One approach to send correct JSON in the data parameter is to refactor your jQuery AJAX to look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/DeletePost',
    type: 'POST',
    data: "{ 'adrId': 6 }",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert("success");
    },
    async: true,
    processData: false
});
```

Or you can use JSON.stringify as suggested by others.

An alternative approach would be to send your data as `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` which is the default, and that way you don't have to change your data parameter. The code would be much simplified:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/DeletePost',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { adrId: 6 },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert("success");
    },
    async: true
});
```

JQuery will recognize that the result is valid JSON.

Comment: @EDIT: Fail... Sorry, I forgot that my controller is called the "Post", a long time I used applications from Microsoft, where the controller was called "Home" and so out of habit ... Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#dialog").dialog(
        {
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    $.ajax({
                       ...
                        data: JSON.stringify({ adrId: 6 }),
                       ...
                    });
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }

            }
        });
    jQuery('.delete').click(function () {

    })
})</script>
```